# Laravel vue return 401 error in api routes

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js

so i have a route group in my `api.php` file like:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth:api'], function(){
//routes
});
```

The problem with this group is that is returning `401` error.

**Why?**

I guess my cookies/session whatever it is, is expired and it return 401 error (while user is not aware of it).

**Issue**

The problem here is laravel keeps my user logged in for `SESSION_LIFETIME=120` but my api is sett to `60` (not sure about this yet)

```
'api' => [
  'throttle:60,1',
  'bindings',
],
```

## Question

1. What should I do in order to logout user after session has expired
   so the next time user visits my site not get into `401` error and
   know he/she is already logged out and need to login again?

## Update

I've made a middleware in order to check session lifetime and logout user if it's expire, but i can't get `lifetime` value out of it.

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $bag = Session::all();
        $max = config('session.lifetime') * 60; // min to hours conversion
        if (($bag && $max < (time() - $bag->getLastUsed()))) {
            $request->session()->flush(); // remove all the session data
            Auth::logout(); // logout user
        }
        return $next($request);
    }
```

Comment: Side note: `throttle:60,1` doesn't mean a 60 minute session length. It has nothing to do with sessions. That line means an IP address is limited to 60 requests per minute for those routes.

Answer (score 2):

The `auth:api` middleware means Laravel will check for a `Authorization: Bearer <access token>` header with the request, and return a 401 if it's not present or valid.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/passport#protecting-routes

Cookies and sessions don't apply here - it's a totally different form of authorization.

Comment: ok, how should i fix this issue? i think i need auto logout for my users when session expires

Comment: Are you using an API or not? If you're using an API, your users need to pass the proper header. If you're not, you should use web.php for your routes.

Comment: @dtbarne I'm getting my data with api route because later i have plan to use that route for my mobile app.

Comment: Im using API, then?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to add this line in the Kernel.php file :

```
'web' => [
    // Other middleware...
    \Laravel\Passport\Http\Middleware\CreateFreshApiToken::class,
],
```

Source : https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/passport#consuming-your-api-with-javascript